# How can python script find the button in Qt application using qtwebdriver?

Tags: python, qt, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an app QCalculator with qtwebdriver:
https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/pull/27/files

I am trying to write simple python test, that will test this calculator,
here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:9517'
)
driver.get("qtwidget://Calculator");

btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[@name='5']")[0]
btn.click();
```

This is interface of  Calculator

[image]

The script is supposed to click on number "5", but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testCalculator.py", line 12, in <module>
    btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[@name='5']")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Buttons are created like this: (in the link below on github)

```
 for (int i = 1; i < NumDigitButtons; ++i) {
         int row = ((9 - i) / 3) + 2;
         int column = ((i - 1) % 3) + 1;
         mainLayout->addWidget(digitButtons[i], row, column);
     }
```

How to change this code ("//Button[@name='5']")[0] to find the button ?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
    btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[@name='5']")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

...implies that the *List* initialized through the `find_elements_by_xpath()` method was an **empty list**. So when you tried to invoke the  first element of the list through the **index** `[0]` *IndexError* was raised.

### Solution

- A proper solution would be to construct a *Locator Strategy* which identifies the element uniquely. Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)
- Perhaps as per your line of code `btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[@name='5']")[0]` the *tag* name should have been **button** instead of *Button*.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. I found the way to find the button: btn5 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//Button[@text='5']")[0]. But I have other problem - I need to located QLineEdit widget, in where the result is stored. In code element created like this display = new QLineEdit("0"); I tried this in my python script: elementDisplay = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//QLineEdit[@name='display']")[0]
but it didn't work.

Comment: @VFbvb If you have a new question feel free to raise a new ticket, Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.